# Small, fast, client-side Javascript database with 'update-as-you-type' functionality?

Tags: javascript, database, performance, client-side

I have a database no more than say 100k which I'd like to use as reference documentation for my software. It's just a simple table really - around 5 columns by a couple of hundred rows. I am looking for a decent Javascript database library; one which would feature:

- Sorting by column
- A tiny size. Has to be small as it is sent to the user (since I don't want anything server-side). Say no more than 50-100k.
- "Update-as-you-type" functionality, and by that I mean, you can type in a filter box, and the rows filter out instantly on the HTML page, or near instantly as you're typing (client-side processing only). If no input in the filter is given, all the results would display on a single large HTML page.
- Searches that allow for partial matches of any cell in the table, and preferably allow NOT, OR and obviously AND.

Furthermore, it should be free/cheap, easy to use and install, perhaps working on a CSV data file for its data.

Is there anything out there that fits the bill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)  OR [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) it has most of that what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I went with DataTables in the end - it's ideal!